# Google Maps Api Geocode get city by a few letters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I found Google Maps Api for searching cities. When I use link
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=London&sensor=false i get information about all London's cities on the world.

My question is How to use that Api to found cities names by a few first letter,
for example, I use `?address=Lon` and I would like get London (all), Lonsdale, Longville, etc...

There some solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may request the [places-autocomplete-service](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) (use a types-parameter with the value `(cities)`)

Sample: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=lon&sensor=false&types=(cities)&key=yourGoogleMapsKey`

Comment: and how can I fetch the city later on?
I need to fetch the city and country only, what is the way possible for this?